# Run code when the tab or browser windows is closed, but not on page reload

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, page-refresh, onbeforeunload

I want to run a javascript function when the user closes the tab or window, but not if the user simply refreshes the page.

I tried an event handler for the `beforeunload` event, but it will also get triggered on a page reload.
Is there a way to ignore page reloads with the `beforeunload` event, or are there other events that could solve my problem?

Here is my current code:

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Remove this tab from sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.removeItem(tabKey);

    // Notify other tabs to close this tab
    const activeTabs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(tabKey)) || [];
    const updatedTabs = activeTabs.filter((id) => id !== tabId);

    if (updatedTabs?.length === 0) {
        // All tabs are closed, execute your code
        const id = events.getIdentifier();
        let URL =
            API_URL +
            "chat/change-status?url=" +
            FIREBASE_FUNCTIONS_URL +
            "&id=" +
            id +
            "&status=" +
            Visitor_status.inactive +
            "&chat_status=" +
            chat_status.no_action;
        fetch(URL, {
            keepalive: true,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no real way to know the difference.... Thousands of questions on this subject all with hacky ways to solve it that are not going to work. And the fetch request you make will be in a race condition with the browser exiting so you may or may not get it.

Answer (score 1):

- The beforeunload event is typically triggered both when refreshing
  the page and when closing the tab or browser. In modern browsers,
  there is no built-in way to distinguish between a page refresh and a
  tab/browser close within the beforeunload event.

However, there's a workaround:

- Listen for the visibilitychange event. If the page's visibility
  changes to hidden (which occurs before a refresh or tab/browser
  close), set a flag. Within the beforeunload event, check if the flag
  has been set. If it has, the action is likely a refresh. If it
  hasn't, the action is likely a close.

  ```
   let isTabHidden = false;

  // Detect when the visibility of the page changes
   document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
   if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
       isTabHidden = true;
   }
  });

   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
   // Check if the tab's visibility has changed to hidden
   if (isTabHidden) {
   return; 
   }

   // ... (The rest of your code remains unchanged.)
  });
  ```

Comment: Not returning from here instead the other code is not executing.

Comment: Can you let me know whats your use case? Like you can store something in local storage and access it. On refresh you can get it back again. But on closing the tab it goes away. So that maybe one use case.

Comment: Basically, My use case is I have chat app and from visitor side I want that if visitor closes tab/window then I have to run API that basically change the status of that visitor from active to inactive, but when the page is being refreshed then also the function is triggering thats the problem and thats why I need an event on only close tab/window not on refresh .

Comment: beforeunload event does not differentiate between a refresh and a close. And also if you write any hack for this, I am not sure that would work across all browsers because this might fail and is not a legit way.

Comment: Change the status to inactive onbeforeunload and to active after the page has been (re-)loaded. Even better, let the page "ping" the server every minute or so and change the status to inactive if there are no more pings.

Comment: This is already working in my scenerio. But, the case is I want to add a log "visitor left" if visitor closes a tab or window but when user reload the page the log is created that "visitor left" even the visitor is on page and that is what I don't want.